# Подгрузка внешних стилей элементов в XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, шаблоны, style

Имеется приложение, в котором кнопки, текстовые поля, чекбоксы и прочее кастомные. Каждый раз добавлять необходимые стили элементов в XAML каждого окна считаю не комильфо, т.к. зачастую большую часть кода занимают именно они.

Есть ли возможность "подгружать их", например, из уже готовых шаблонов стилей этих элементов? И если да, то покажите пример такого использования.

Comment: В App.xaml добавьте и они подхватятся всеми окнами, если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: Да. Спасибо. Стили стали глобальными. Оформите как ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто поместите стили в App.xaml и они станут доступны во всех окнах приложения.